# reactjs datepicker date format

Tags: reactjs, date, datepicker

Beginner with ReactJS, I use now the wonderful ReactJS Datepicker. Questions about my custom date format :

1. i found no doc to explain all the possibilities like M is month, MM is month on 2 letters, etc. (shall I look to the github code? which source?)
2. How to add the name of the day... like Saturday. I tried dddd but it shows the number of the day with 2 leading 0 before !!
3. How to exclude the non office hour (like hours 0 to 8 and 20 to 23), I tried the excludesTimes below but no way.

Here is my code :

```
<DatePicker
    selected={this.state.startDate}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    locale={fr}
    showTimeSelect
    timeFormat="HH:mm"
    timeIntervals={60}
    dateFormat="dddd, DDD, ddd, d, dd MMMM yyyy à HH'h'mm"
    timeCaption="Heure"
    minDate={new Date()}
    showDisabledMonthNavigation
    placeholderText="Choisir ici ..."
    excludeTimes={[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
/>
```

Date shown in input field is then :

> 0023, 082, 023, 23, 23 mars 2019 à 20h00

Thanks

Comment: rezvani-datepicker
return actual new Date() so you can change the format to what ever you want.
https://github.com/Abolfazl2647/rn-datepicker/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

React datepicker uses **Moment.js** for dates, I think you should review the docs at [his website](https://momentjs.com/).

For example `MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a` should return a date formated as  `March 21st 2019, 8:50:37 am`.

**EDIT**

I went to the repo and it appears the author removed moment from package, so I gave a try to the formatting dates guide found [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) and it appears to be working now! Per example use "eeee" if you want day of the week.

I made a working example at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ov8z0zvl9).

Comment: Thank for your help, but it does not solve.. using dateFormat="MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a" , it displays "March 81st 2019, 8:43:14 PM" .. whereas I ran "npm install moment as you requested.. can you give more clue ?

Comment: I went to the repo and it appears the author removed moment, so I gave a try to the formatting dates guide found [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) and it appears to be working now! Per example, use "eeee" if you want day of the week. I made you a working example at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ov8z0zvl9).

Comment: PERFECT, you solve it !It is a pity that one must look into the code to understand the use of the software .. but that is current life !
We can mark this ticket as solved (note the solution is in the previous comment, and not the beginning of te answer speaking about moment.js).

Comment: Bad documented libraries are a plague...I edited the answer if you want to mark it as approved solution :)

Comment: Link from @PabloHuetCarrasco is outdated. Author is using [format from date-fns package](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format)

Answer (score 1):

You also can convert manually ...

```
  const convertDate = str => {
  str = str.toString();
  let parts = str.split(" ");
  let months = {
    Jan: "01",
    Feb: "02",
    Mar: "03",
    Apr: "04",
    May: "05",
    Jun: "06",
    Jul: "07",
    Aug: "08",
    Sep: "09",
    Oct: "10",
    Nov: "11",
    Dec: "12"
  };
  return parts[3] + "-" + months[parts[1]] + "-" + parts[2];
};
```

:) Reinventing the wheel

Comment: ugh. I was trying to get away from doing that but credit for you for just writing code instead of relying on someone having written it already!